# How can I preserve share paths when moving a share to a new server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, share

I have 2 servers and I just moved most of the shares from server1 (SBS 2003 server) to server2 (Server 2003 Standard).

However, in sharepoint there are a lot of links that refer to the old server by name, ie, `\\server1\accounts`.

How can I have the shares physically on the new (larger) server, while preserving these links and having them still work.

Cheers,

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can go by the way which ms advising - use File Server Migration Toolkit ([whitepaper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/e/b/4eb8df62-08cb-420f-a41b-6d10452335cc/FSMT%20Whitepaper.doc))

It creates dfs root folder, in which both servers (old and new) are targeted. And than you remove old server fro dfs.

Comment: turns out to 'maintain original UNC paths' it requires server 2003 _enterprise_ or higher, whereas I am using small business server.

Comment: Although more playing shows that creating a DFS root on the original server pointing at the second server works well.

Answer (score 1):

Are you keeping server1? If not, you can just add a manual DNS-entry in your domain-zone on your AD-server for server1, that points to server2.

Second option might be to rename server1 to something else, and then add a DNS-record for the old name (server1) that points to server2.

Comment: yes we are keeping server1